# Image banner in android

Tags: android

if u check this steam page http://store.steampowered.com/

There is a banner which feature games, It move from right to left scroll horizontal transition which is automatic and can be scrolled left or right on press of button. I want to do same banner in android app. But right now i don't know how to start with. Need some ideas from you guys. I need efficient approach. Is it just one imageview and drawing and doing transition on its canvas. If yes then how does it work for my situation which is i am fetching images from web service via xml. SO this banner contents would be dynamic. The url of image will be in xml and i have to render those images in this banner with those transition as seen in steam page.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe a `Gallery`? Or a `ViewPager` of `ImageViews`?

Comment: Hi gallery looks promising. But i want exactly like steam. I want to have canvas/view covering full width of screen and specific height and wnat to make only one pic visible on that canvas area. So how wud i achieve that. In gallery transition is fine but how do i customize look and i want auto scrolling feature also. Thanks for ur response.

Comment: You can use a [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html) with animations *(see `setInAnimation()` and `setOutAnimation()`)* and a auto-switch interval *(see `setAutoStart()` and `setFlipInterval()`)*.

Comment: I have one doubt. Does viewflipper works between different UI's. Or transition happens between images ? Thanks for ur reply.

Comment: ok according to docs it happens between view. Since my contents are dynamic that there can be 5 images then later 10 and so on. So what i am thinking is to use just two UI and do scroll animation between them, so when one view hided i programatically assign concerned image to it. Because i don't want to use 20 views if i have 20 images in my xml. What u suggest ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using a ViewFlipper and dynamically (in code) adding ImageViews. Keep in mind that loading multiple Images is very memory heavy.

You could load the shown picture +- 1 and adding/removing images on-the-fly when the shown image is switched. With this approach it would save memory and should be efficient.